# Does the monoid of sets of numbers with addition have a name?

Tags: monoid

The monoid is the set of all sets of integers (but reals or complex numbers could work too). Addition between two elements is defined as $a+b = \{\ x+y\ |\ x \in a,\ y \in b\ \}$. As far as I can tell, the only category of algebraic structures this fits into is monoids, since it's not a group.

Is this structure known or used anywhere, and does it have a name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This operation is called [Minkowski addition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition). I'm not aware of any special name for the algebraic structure of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z})$ (or whatever) equipped with Minkowski addition though.

Answer (score 1):

Another name for the operation is [sumset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumset), and it's studied in [Arithmetic combinatronics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_combinatorics).

Answer (score 1):

More generally, if $M$ is a monoid, the set $\mathcal{P}(M)$ of subsets of $M$ is a monoid for the following operation: given $X, Y \in \mathcal{P}(M)$,
$$
XY = \{xy \mid x \in X, y \in Y \}
$$ 
The monoid $\mathcal{P}(M)$ is sometimes called the *power monoid* of $M$.